# Find the number of 1s in the same position in two arrays

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
A = [0,0,0,1,0,1]
B = [0,0,1,1,1,1]
```

I want to find the number of 1s in the same position in both lists.

The answer for these arrays would be 2.

Answer (score 19):

A little shorter and hopefully more pythonic way:

```
>>> A=[0,0,0,1,0,1]
>>> B=[0,0,1,1,1,1]

x = sum(1 for a,b in zip(A,B) if (a==b==1))
>>> x
2
```

Comment: Great answer.  As python allows you to chain comparison operators you can have (a == b == 1) for the if.

Comment: you don't need brackets around comparison

Comment: I like this answer, just uses native python function however the performance is suffering, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877059/comparing-two-arrays/877450#877450 for some performance test against a simple numpy version

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert of Python, but what is wrong with a simple loop from start to end of first array?

In C# I would do something like:

```
int match=0;

for (int cnt=0; cnt< A.Count;cnt++)
{
    if ((A[cnt]==B[cnt]==1)) match++;
}
```

Would that be possible in your language?

Comment: "Would that be possible in your language?" Yes. :)

Comment: Possible, yes, but not idiomatic. Slightly faster for long lists, it would seem. For two random lists of length 10'000, your solution (translated to python) took 0.003s on my system, while 'drakosha' took 0.005 and 'bendin' took 0.020s.

Comment: Stranger yet, for 1'000'000 elements: berggreendk=0.031s, bendin=0.045, drakosha=1.02s which probably doesn't prove anything other than the fact that micro-benchmarking is hard to do right.

Comment: So does this conclude that my algoritm construction would be the fastest or did I misinterpret these comments?

Comment: @BerggreenDK:  I believe your algorithm is indeed faster, and not just for long lists.  It's actually kind of surprising and disappointing, since it is so clearly not idiomatic.

Comment: @JohnY I find simplicity usually beats tricks and short hands and unnecessarily unclear code. Not only can you almost immediately tell what the code is doing, it also becomes easier to add a series of conditions and expressions if needed for more complex matches later down the road. It's also super easy for the compiler to optimize this.

Comment: @dennmat: Who said anything about tricks and shorthands? Python tries to be simple and clear. And how do you know that what is easy for the C# compiler (or underlying .NET compiler) to optimize is easy for the Python compiler to optimize? Python is usually quite slow at explicit loops; thus it is both more idiomatic *and* usually faster to make use of Python's sets, `map`, comprehensions, etc. And these features of the language are there for clarity, not for "tricks". Ask a Lisp or Haskell programmer whether a C-style `for` loop is clearer than a map or comprehension.

Comment: @JohnY Because you can't optimize a function call, without doing C style inline functions. Where as loops often are and have been optimized in compilers for a very long time where ever possible. I get that there is a time and place for using the convenience methods. And yes some are implemented in C which tend to result in quicker execution. However for something as simple as looping through a list and incrementing a counter, you'll have a hard time finding a way to optimize that process by adding function calls to the solution.

Comment: @dennmat: For something as simple as looping through **one** list and incrementing a counter, it is hard to do it *slower* than a `for` loop in Python. You agree that built-in functions in Python which do their loops in C do tend to be quicker (than looping in the Python interpreter), so I'm not sure which function calls you are talking about which are slower than Python `for` loops.

Comment: By the way, the specific "translation" of this algorithm into Python does matter.  For the most literal interpretation of this C-style `for` loop (into a `while` loop with explicit initialization of `cnt` at the beginning and explicit incrementing of `cnt` inside the loop), this algorithm is actually about the same speed as John Pirie's. If you **use Python idioms** to translate this algorithm (`for` loop with `enumerate`) it is nearly twice as fast (because `enumerate` increments `cnt` in C rather than Python).

Answer (score 1):

Motivated by brief need to be perverse, I offer the following solution:

```
A = [0,0,0,1,0,1]
B = [0,0,1,1,1,1]

print len(set(i for i, n in enumerate(A) if n == 1) &
          set(i for i, n in enumerate(B) if n == 1))
```

(Drakosha's suggestion is a far more reasonable way to solve this problem. This just demonstrates that one can often look at the same problem in different ways.)

Comment: Nice idea, however it's O(NlogN) opposed to my O(N) solution. You'll need to supply preversed and fast version ;)

Answer (score 0):

With [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org):

```
>>> from scipy import array
>>> A=array([0,0,0,1,0,1])
>>> B=array([0,0,1,1,1,1])

>>> A==B
array([ True,  True, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> sum(A==B)
4

>>> A!=B
array([False, False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> sum(A!=B)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here comes another method which exploits the fact that the array just contains zeros and ones.

The scalar product of two vectors x and y is sum( x(i)*y(i) ) the only situation yielding a non zero result is if x(i)==y(i)==1 thus using numpy for instance

```
from numpy import *
x = array([0,0,0,1,0,1])
y = array([0,0,1,1,1,1])
print dot(x,y)
```

simple and nice. This method does n multiplications and adds n-1 times, however there are fast implementations using SSE, GPGPU, vectorisation, (add your fancy word here) for dot products (scalar products)

I timed the numpy-method against this method:

```
sum(1 for a,b in zip(x,y) if (a==b==1))
```

and found that for 1000000 loops the numpy-version did it in 2121ms and the zip-method did it in 9502ms thus the numpy-version is a lot faster

I did a better analysis of the efectivness and found that
for n element(s) in the array the zip method took t1 ms and the dot product took t2 ms for one itteration

```
elements      zip       dot
1          0.0030    0.0207
10         0.0063    0.0230
100        0.0393    0.0476
1000       0.3696    0.2932
10000      7.6144    2.7781
100000   115.8824   30.1305
```

From this data one could draw the conclusion that if the number of elements in the array is expected to (in mean) be more than 350 (or say 1000) one should consider to use the dot-product method instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
[A[i]+B[i] for i in range(min([len(A), len(B)]))].count(2)
```

Basically this just creates a new list which has all the elements of the other two added together.  You know there were two 1's if the sum is 2 (assuming only 0's and 1's in the list).  Therefore just perform the count operation on 2.